# Can't start httpd on RHEL 7

Tags: rhel, apache-httpd

I can't start httpd on RHEL 7.

```
[root@machine]# systemctl restart httpd
Failed to restart httpd.service: Unit not found.
```

I tried...

```
yum update -y
yum install httpd -y
systemctl restart httpd
```

Same result.  Apache config looks OK:

```
[root@machine]# httpd -t
Syntax OK
```

Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.7 (Maipo)

---

```
[root@machine me]# rpm -q httpd
httpd-2.4.6-90.el7.x86_64
```

...

```
[root@machine me]# systemctl status httpd
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2020-01-27 15:38:54 CST; 1 day 16h ago
     Docs: man:httpd(8)
           man:apachectl(8)
  Process: 36851 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 36849 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 36849 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jan 27 15:38:54 faspbsy0002 httpd[36849]: (98)Address already in use: AH0007...0
Jan 27 15:38:54 faspbsy0002 httpd[36849]: (98)Address already in use: AH0007...0
Jan 27 15:38:54 faspbsy0002 httpd[36849]: no listening sockets available, sh...n
Jan 27 15:38:54 faspbsy0002 httpd[36849]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
Jan 27 15:38:54 faspbsy0002 systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, ...E
Jan 27 15:38:54 faspbsy0002 kill[36851]: kill: cannot find process ""
Jan 27 15:38:54 faspbsy0002 systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exite...1
Jan 27 15:38:54 faspbsy0002 systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Jan 27 15:38:54 faspbsy0002 systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Jan 27 15:38:54 faspbsy0002 systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

Comment: did you try with service httpd start ?

Comment: What is the output of `rpm -q httpd`?  Possibly also `rpm -ql httpd | grep service` and `systemctl list-unit-files | grep http`.  If those return results, does `systemctl status httpd` output anything?  Were there any post-install errors after you initially installed `httpd`?

Comment: @GracefulRestart -- I will edit my question to add the output from those commands.

Comment: Do `journalctl -xf -l --unit httpd` to see what errors it gets. The problem shown by your log is that the address is already in use, but the line is shortened. The `-l` will show you the full error. "Address already in use" probably means that there are earlier instances that have not shut down completely (IIRC, there is also a delay when a TCP socket is shut down and before it is released, so maybe you are not waiting long enough for the previous failed restart to clean up before retrying).

Comment: [root@faspbsy0002 me]# journalctl -xf -l --unit httpd 
... Result at https://pastebin.com/UMb3Hd2s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be that I had two different versions of Apache installed: the standard version and one from Red Hat Software Collections.

```
[root@faspbsy0002 httpd24]# yum list installed | grep httpd
httpd.x86_64                  2.4.6-90.el7             @rhel-7-server-rpms      
httpd-tools.x86_64            2.4.6-90.el7             @rhel-7-server-rpms      
httpd24-httpd.x86_64          2.4.34-7.el7.1           @rhel-server-rhscl-7-rpms
httpd24-httpd-tools.x86_64    2.4.34-7.el7.1           @rhel-server-rhscl-7-rpms
httpd24-libcurl.x86_64        7.61.1-2.el7             @rhel-server-rhscl-7-rpms
httpd24-libnghttp2.x86_64     1.7.1-7.el7              @rhel-server-rhscl-7-rpms
httpd24-mod_ssl.x86_64        1:2.4.34-7.el7.1         @rhel-server-rhscl-7-rpms
httpd24-runtime.x86_64        1.1-18.el7               @rhel-server-rhscl-7-rpms
```

To restart Apache, I needed to do...

```
systemctl restart httpd24-httpd
```

And I should probably also remove the version of Apache I don't use.

I also discovered that **httpd -V** is misleading in this situation, because it gives the httpd_root and document_root of the standard Apache, but that was not the Apache in use.

Answer (score 0):

Unit not found seems to me that `httpd` is not serviced properly.

Try the following

```
systemctl is-enabled httpd
systemctl is-active httpd
```

If both return again `unit not found`, try to install `httpd` again, make a backup of your config first.

```
yum remove httpd

yum search apache
yum install httpd
```

Comment: systemctl is-enabled httpd -> disabled.

Comment: systemctl is-active httpd -> failed

Comment: After removing httpd, search apache and install httpd, I am still unable to start apache. You can see the output from my attempts to start apache, and from journalctl, at https://pastebin.com/tb5BQWDa

Comment: you are trying to start a the http in a port that is already used by another service. Please provide the output of netstat -tulnp

Comment: @BANJOSA -- Output at https://pastebin.com/szvXnn16

Comment: please refer to lines 8 and 12. it states that you already have a httpd service running on port 443 and 80. on the same machine please open a browser and execute http://127.0.0.1 or in a terminal use curl http://127.0.0.1

Comment: @BANJOSA -- How can I address this? I don't know what to do about an httpd service running on port 443 and 80.  Normally I just start apache and it works, so this is a detail of administration that I'm not familiar with.

Comment: (Nothing happens when I curl 127.0.0.1 from the same server. There is no output or error.)

Comment: In my apache config, I see "Listen 80" but nothing about 443.

Comment: in my apaches i use 2 different conf files one http.conf for the main configurations for http and one ssl.conf for the https, hence http.conf for port 80 and ssl.conf for port 443.

Comment: If I change into my HTTPD root (/etc/httpd) and then grep for 443, it comes up empty.  There is no 443 string anywhere in the config.  There is no ssl.conf.